# Inverse Galois problem

Tags: finite-groups, galois-theory, inverse-problems, galois-extensions

The inverse Galois problem conjectures that every finite group is (isomorphic to) the Galois group of some Galois extension of $\mathbb Q$, however it is not known.

> My question is: what is the smallest finite group such that it is not known whether it is the Galois Group of such an extension?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem#Partial_results seems to contain what you want (no idea whether it's state of the art)

Comment: This is a research question, you'd better ask it on MO

Comment: For examples, see the first part of the Wiki. article on the subject. The "Bible" is of course the book of Malle-Matzat (1999), but a good not too technical and more recent (2011= bicentennial of Galois' birth) account can be found in  www.galois.ihp.fr/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/P.-Debes.pdf

Comment: Thx nguyen quang and thx Tsemo Aristide for the tip. I did not know that MO is for reasearch questions.